# How to use Substring to pull multiple items from a field

Tags: sql-server, substring

First post - I am trying to pull ten different pieces of information from a single field.  Let me start with this is not my table, just what I was given to work with.  This is a varchar max field.

```
'3350|@|1234567|~|3351|@|8/1/2017|~|3352|@|Acme|~|3353|~|10000.00|~|3354|@||~|3355|@||~3356|@|Yes|~|3357|@|Doe,John|~|3358|@|CA|~|3359|@|5551212'
```

I know that the numbers that start with 33 are keys telling me what information is in that section.  3350 has the invoice #1234567. 3351 has the invoice date of 8/1/17. etc. 3354 and 3355 were left null. The keys are unchanging and will be the same for every record in the table.

I need to pull the data from between 3350|@| and |~|3351 to get my invoice# and between 3351|@| and |~|3352 to get my date, etc, but I am struggling with how to word this.  Any help would be appreciated and any critiques on my first post will be taken constructively.

Comment: What version of SQL you running? I'm thinking it's probably going to be easiest to split the string on `~`, yielding a table contanining each chunk of data. From there, you can substring each individual value pretty easily. If you're running SQL 2016+ there's a native string splitting function. Otherwise, you'd have to roll your own.

Comment: Are you only pulling your data from this one field in a single record?  Or do you have to do this across multiple rows?

Comment: I would recommend you start by getting a string splitter routine (or, if you are using SQL Server 2016 or higher, using the built-in SPLIT_STRING() function). split the string on `|~|` or just the tilde. You then have the multiple fragments in place. Using `CHARINDEX()`,  and `LEFT()`/`RIGHT()` (or `SUBSTRING()`) on the fragments, it will be easy to get the information you are looking for

Comment: Note that, if you split the string on a tilde, you will need to remove any leading or trailing pipe characters from your individual data fragment for easier processing. e.g. the first item would be `3350|@|1234567|` (no leading pipe), the last item would be `'|3359|@|5551212'` (no trailing pipe), and all of the items in the middle would have both leading and trailing pipes.  Splitting on `|~|` eliminates the leading and trailing pipes.

Comment: I am running on SQL2008 and this will be done across multiple rows.  I will research string splitting.  Thanks to everyone for the quick responses.

Comment: If you wanted to handle in code you could split to array first on ~, replace all pipe bars with nothing, then check for a value after @ and populate a table with or another array with key and invoice.

Comment: Were you looking for rows or columns?  Also is the sample malformed around 3353 & 10000.00 ?  Seem to break the pattern

Comment: Ideally I would like them in their own columns.  And yes, it should be 3353|@|10000.00.  Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

The @YourTable is just a table variable used for demonstration / illustration

**For Rows - Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'3350|@|1234567|~|3351|@|8/1/2017|~|3352|@|Acme|~|3353|@|10000.00|~|3354|@||~|3355|@||~|3356|@|Yes|~|3357|@|Doe,John|~|3358|@|CA|~|3359|@|5551212')


Select A.ID
      ,Item  = left(RetVal,charindex('|@|',RetVal+'|@|')-1)
      ,Value = right(RetVal,len(RetVal)-charindex('|@|',RetVal+'|@|')-2)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.SomeCol,'|~|') B
```

**Returns**

[image]

**For Columns - Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'3350|@|1234567|~|3351|@|8/1/2017|~|3352|@|Acme|~|3353|@|10000.00|~|3354|@||~|3355|@||~|3356|@|Yes|~|3357|@|Doe,John|~|3358|@|CA|~|3359|@|5551212')

Select *
 From (
        Select A.ID
              ,Item  = left(RetVal,charindex('|@|',RetVal+'|@|')-1)
              ,Value = right(RetVal,len(RetVal)-charindex('|@|',RetVal+'|@|')-2)
         From  @YourTable A
         Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.SomeCol,'|~|') B
       ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in ([3350],[3351],[3352],[3353],[3354],[3355],[3356],[3357],[3358],[3359]) ) p
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Comment: That worked and it's the most beautiful thing I've ever seen. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JDN469 Happy to help,

Answer (score 0):

You can try a tally based splitter like below

```
declare @t table ( id int, col nvarchar(max));
insert into @t values
(1, '3350|@|1234567|~|3351|@|8/1/2017|~|3352|@|Acme|~|3353|~|10000.00|~|3354|@||~|3355|@||~3356|@|Yes|~|3357|@|Doe,John|~|3358|@|CA|~|3359|@|5551212')
,(2, '3350|@|123334567|~|3351|@|8/2/2017|~|3352|@|Acme|~|3353|~|10000.00|~|3354|@||~|3355|@||~3356|@|Yes|~|3357|@|Doe,John|~|3358|@|CA|~|3359|@|5551212');

select 
    id,
    case 
    when split_values like '3350|@|%' then 'id' 
    when split_values like '3351|@|%' then 'date'
    end as fieldname,
    SUBSTRING(split_values,8,LEN(split_values)-7) as value
from 
(
    select 
        --t.col as col,
        row_number() over (partition by t.col order by t1.N asc) as row_num,
        t.id,
        SUBSTRING( t.col, t1.N, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|~|',t.col,t1.N),0)-t1.N,8000)) as split_values
    from @t t 
        join
        (
            select 
                t.col,
                1 as N 
            from @t t  
                UNION ALL
            select 
                t.col,
                t1.N + 3 as N
            from @t t 
                join
                (
                 select 
                    top 8000
                        row_number() over(order by (select NULL)) as N 
                 from 
                    sys.objects s1 
                        cross join 
                   sys.objects s2 
                ) t1 
            on SUBSTRING(t.col,t1.N,3) = '|~|'
         ) t1
         on t1.col=t.col
)a
where 
    split_values like '3350|@|%' or 
    split_values like '3351|@|%'
```

<kbd>**[Live demo](http://rextester.com/HIXHPM38128)**</kbd>